# Hide server IP from received-header (STMP via sendgrid)

Tags: email

I use a PHP-CMS to send emails via SMTP. The problem is that I want to secure my server against DDoS, so I've installed CloudFlare and I want to hide my real server IP. When users get an email by the PHP-CMS, they can see the IP in the Email header (Received:). How can I hide this information?

I use sendgrid for sending emails and I thought this would hide my server IP, but that is not working at all.

Comment: So the users that you send email to are going to extract your server ip address from the email header and then DDOS you?

Answer (score 1):

You can forward the SMTP port from CMS host to the MTA host so your PHP will be sure messages are submitted locally. But they will be submitted to the remote MTA via `127.0.0.1`. On the CMS host stop the local MTA and launch this:

```
ssh -f -N -L 25:127.0.0.1:25 user@mta.host.com
```

The `Received` header will contain only MTA's IP and 127.0.0.1 for submitter instead of CMS's IP.

Comment: Does not work: ssh: connect to host smtp.sendgrid.net port 22: Connection timed out! Can I configure sendmail so it won't send my server IP via Received by?

Answer (score 0):

Just firewall inbound traffic to only come from cloudflare, ssh via your jump box or configure a persistent vpn like openvpn.

Also,  it's a security/abuse requirement by sendgrid to post your ip on the header,  unless you host it yourself and scrub received headers you aren't going to be able to avoid that.